# MediaElement: stop triggering MarkerReached event after pause and resume video

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mediaelement, resume, timelinemarkers

My code:

```
private void myPlayer_MarkerReached(object sender, TimelineMarkerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // change state of Text Line
}
private void myPlayer_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     if (myPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing) myPlayer.Pause();
     if (myPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused || myPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Stopped) myPlayer.Play();            
}
```

I add `Markers` to the `MediaElement` object (here `myPlayer`), then i start video. Everything is fine and works as i wanted to work. But when i pause and resume video (using `myPlayer_Tap` event) function `myPlayer_MarkerReached` doesnt trigger anymore. I checked if `Markers` werent deleted but the number is the same as after add my `Markers` (it means that `Markers` are still there) but it seems like `MediaElement` cant see them.

Any ideas why?

I code in VS2013 for Windows Phone 8.